# Is there a way to use the ActiveMQ Ajax servlet with Tomee?

Tags: ajax, jms, tomcat7, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

Is there a way to use the ActiveMQ Ajax servlet with Tomee?

This documentation page implies that it "just works": http://activemq.apache.org/tomee.html

But, elsewhere, it is made clear that the servlet depends upon Jetty: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/AjaxServlet-on-Tomcat-td3601798.html. Note that user Hexaplus says he/she got it working by including the Jetty libraries.

I have not had success following Hexaplus's instructions; I get the following error stacktrace

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AjaxServlet] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1673)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1666)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1023)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation.suspend(Servlet3Continuation.java:202)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageListenerServlet.doMessages(MessageListenerServlet.java:326)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageListenerServlet.doGet(MessageListenerServlet.java:246)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet.doGet(AjaxServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

Other people report the same problem, for example: (can't post more than 2 links)

```
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/activemq-users/201302.mbox/%3C1359730513047-4662633.post@n4.nabble.com%3E
```